# Can I reinstall Ubuntu off of another pc?

Tags: reinstall, surface

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have messed up the installation. Is there a way I could run the iso off of another pc?

Comment: You can run the install from a DVD or a USB. Running it across the network is a very complex setup.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop can be re-installed without losing your data files, user configuration and if internet is available during installation, your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled (*if available in Ubuntu repositories*), but you didn't say if your Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was a Desktop or Server installation. Server apps can store configs in system directories which are wiped prior to install thus don't survive. This will work with ISOs using `ubiquity` & `calamares` as the installer (*including flavors*), and is useful for package problem correction, but not user config issues

Comment: Sure, it is easy. Just stick your hard drive in the other computer, or use an external USB enclosure, plug in the installer USB and proceed with installation. Replace the disk in your computer and everything should work. I am not understanding why reinstalling on your computer doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David said in the comment above, running an installation across the network is challenging, but can be done.

I use MAAS for that purpose at work - on a segregated network where it can control access to everything (DNS, tftp, web proxy, and PXE booting, and other details about the network it controls).

It's pretty straightforward to set it up - https://maas.io provides you all teh instructions if that's your direction.  It's not really for home use however, as most home networks don't have the capability to have a segregated network.

Without some sort of tool to provide PXE booting on your network segment and then provide file services to install from, it's pretty challenging to make it work.  It would be a lot easier to download the installation media onto a USB Key with enough space to hold it and boot your computer from that.  You may even be able to enter rescue mode and repair your broken installation.  There are details for most of that on the ubuntu website.

Good luck